# appending a copy of a text block

Tags: awk, vim, sed

I'm working on a `LaTeX` `beamer` presentation where I'd like to add a notes section below each `\item` heading which simply copies its text. For example I have

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Einstein was a clever man.
    \item My favorite equation is,
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation} where
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $m$ is the mass,
        \item $c$ the velocity of light and,
        \item $E$ is the energy.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

and I would like to have

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Einstein was a clever man.
    \note<.>[item]{
          Einstein was a clever man.
    }
    \item My favorite equation is,
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation} where
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $m$ is the mass,
        \item $c$ the velocity of light and,
        \item $E$ is the energy.
    \end{enumerate}

    \note<.>[item] { 
          My favorite equation is,
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2.
    \end{equation where
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $m$ is the mass,
        \item $c$ the velocity of light and,
        \item $E$ is the energy.
    \end{enumerate}
    }
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

How can I do this in `vim`, or using command line tools like `awk` or `sed`?

Via `vim` I'm able to copy-and-append isolated lines starting with the pattern `\item` via

```
:g/^\\item/ copy . | s//\\note\{item\}<.>\{/g
```

but I'm unable to capture the whole block belonging to each top-level  `\item`.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question, which us highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: The diff between the desired outcome and the original state is incoherent with the question which a) doesn't mention adjusting indentation or what should or shouldn't be nested and b) asks for something to happen "below each `\item`".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @romainl . I've fixed the indentation, and that I want each of the top-level `\item` listings to be repeated below them but inside the `\note<.>[item]{...}` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\\begin\{itemize\}/{:a;n;/^\\end\{itemize\}/bb
        /^( {4}|\t)\\item/{
          :b;x;s/^(\s*)\\item(.*)/\1\\note<.*>[item]{\n\1\1\2\n\1}/p;x;h;ba}
        H;ba}' file
```

Focus on lines between `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}`

Make a copy of each `\item` and append the copy to each `\item` stanza, replacing the `\item` command by the desired `\note` command.

N.B. The solution depends on the whitespace indenting the `\item` command, currently the indent is set at 4 spaces but tabs may be used (see regexp at the beginning of the second line).

Comment: You sir are a genius! @potong

Comment: Quick follow up. What if the `\begin{itemize}[<+->] .. \end{itemize}` block was indented one tab/4 spaces forward -- how would the expression change?

Comment: @marital_weeping then change the regexps in the first line of the solution i.e. `/^( {4}|\t)\\begin\{itemize\}/{:a;n;/^( {4}|\t)\\end\{itemize\}/bb`